# td-agent does not work when fluent-plugin-google-cloud on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, td-agent

I installed td-agent on GCP VM, checked that the service ran (through "systemctl status td-agent").
Then I ran "/usr/sbin/td-agent-gem install fluent-plugin-google-cloud" to install stackdriver output plugin. The installation succeeded but td-agent did not work anymore after restart.
systemctl status td-agent showed:

```
Job for td-agent.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status td-agent.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
[ei-platform@gw1 ~]$ sudo systemctl status td-agent.service
   td-agent.service - td-agent: Fluentd based data collector for Treasure Data
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/td-agent.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Wed 2019-10-16 05:05:46 UTC; 5s ago
     Docs: https://docs.treasuredata.com/articles/td-agent
  Process: 32171 ExecStart=/opt/td-agent/embedded/bin/fluentd --log /var/log/td-agent/td-agent.log --daemon /var/run/td-agent/td-agent.pid $TD_AGENT_OPTIONS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

The same worked OK on VMWARE VM.

Any known reason why it fails on GCP?

Comment: Please follow the error message text and "See "journalctl -xe" for details". There could be a clue.

Comment: I issued journalctl  and found error:
/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/stub_specification.rb:116:in `initialize': Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /opt/td-agent/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/specifications..
so I ran chmod and this helped to pass this point, but then it failed with:
[error]: config error file="/etc/td-agent/td-agent.conf" error_class=Fluent::ConfigError error="Unknown output plugin 'google_cloud'. Run 'gem search -rd fluent-plugin' to find plugins"
Any idea why the plugin is not recognized?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found that installation of google-cloud plugin did not add it to td-agent plugin dir, so it was not loaded during startup.

The plugin was placed to /opt/td-agent/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/fluent-plugin-google-cloud-0.7.22/lib/fluent/plugin dir, so I added this dir after -p switch to ExecStart command in /usr/lib/systemd/system/td-agent.service and the plugin was loaded and worked as expected.